# Where do I find the VPN and DNS settings on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, dns, apache-http-server, websocket

I am trying to setup a VPN as I need one for my work. I have been told I will need a service I have full control over so I can connect from my Denmark computer when I am in the UK and probably vice-versa as well. Can anyone tell me how or direct me to any actually usable resources on the subject as a google search has directed me towards a mass of confusing and often inaccurate information on the subject and I really, really need to get this sorted. I will also need Websocket and maybe Apache server as well (not sure if I need the latter if I get the former working) if that affects anything about the initial setup process?

Comment: If you are trying to VPN to work, then the most important thing is to find out what kind of VPN your place of employment supports.  Using a VPN to make services think you have a different geo-location, for example listen to the BBC while not in the UK, is a different kind of use.  But your question seems to indicate that's what you are thinking of.

Comment: And since you are refering to installing services, perhaps you are thinking of a Virtual Private Server (VPS) instead of a Virtual Private Network. (VPN)

Comment: I will be off-site and have had a VPN installed remotely but it no-longer works and attempts at off-site support appear to be failing at the moment. It was a VPN which was installed on my machine previously.

I wouldn't be allowed to listen to the BBC unless it was for work related activities.

Comment: The BBS was just a example.   If you know the name of your company's VPN gateway, you could go to the "Network and Sharing Center"  (I usually rightclick the network icon in the system tray), then in there do "Setup a new connection or network"  and in there, do "connect to a workplace",  next, then "use my internet connection".   But you'll need your credentials etc.